# Using onFocusChange in TextInputLayout messes up hints

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, onfocuschangelistener

I am trying to do a validation + warning when a user leaves a field.

I am using textInputLayout + TextInputEditText and listening on onFocusChanged - pretty basic :-)

My problem is that the hint stays in the top when I use the onFocusChangeListener and I want it to act normal and go to the editText field.

Any ideas?

XML

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/usernameWrapper"
        errorEnabled="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:hint="@string/login_name_hint"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Code

```
findViewById(R.id.username).setOnFocusChangeListener(new 
       View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    setUsernameError("Indtast e-mail (eller brugernavn)");
                }
            }
        });
```

### **Edit:**

**To clarify:** The problem occurs when I leave the EditText. Then I expect the hint to move from label to EditText. It does not. It stays in the label. This only occurs when I set an onFocusChangeListener on the EditText

Comment: Did you try to **edittext.clearFocus();** or focusing somehing different?

Comment: so you want  the hint to be invisible while you set the error? Or you want your hint to be back inside the edittext?

Comment: @MetehanToksoy 
Yes - on both the TextInputEditText and the TextInputLayout.  
It did no difference.

Comment: @Sagar
I want it to be back inside the EditText - normal behavior when not setting an onFocusChangeListener

Comment: You can do a work around by just setting the hint again, use et.setHint(), if nothing else works.

Comment: @NirPatel
Unfortunately setHint is not working eiter :-(
If I set hint on TextInputLayout it just updates the text in the label (on top) if I set it on TextInputEditText, it sets the hint, but does not remove the toplabel hint.
If I remove the toplabel hint and set it on TextInputEditText, it does not go to toplabel when re-entering the field :-(

Comment: Try writing below after editText.clearfocus();

this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

Comment: @NirPatel Unfortunately clearFocus and setSoftInputmode did not work either

Answer (score 0):

Its behaving as expected and has no relation between setting the  `onFocusChangedListener`

By default framework tries to give focus to the first focusable View from the top. Since the `TextInputEditText` is the only focusable view, it will be focused and your hint will stay in top when screen is launched. If you don't want this behavior, there are  two options:

1. Make your parent view focusable  by setting `android:focusable` and `android:focusableInTouchMode` as follows:

   ```
   <LinearLayout 
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:focusable="true"
             android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
          android:id="@+id/usernameWrapper"
          errorEnabled="true"
          android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

          <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
              android:id="@+id/username"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:hint="@string/tv2login_name_hint"
              android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

      </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

   Whenever you are done editing, call `editText.clearFocus()`
2. Don't use `TextInputLayout` but rather use simple `EditText`

Comment: I did not add all of the code to keep it simple
I have a second field similar to the first and enters that. So focus should be gone from the first - as I understand it?
I will try to use EditText instead and see if that works .-)

Comment: I just illustrated how to change focus to parent view. You can add `android:focusable` and `android:focusableInTouchMode` to any parent view

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I had another task I had to focus on.
I added the android:focusable="true" and android:focusableInTouchMode="true", but i did not work :-( 
But thx for the suggestion

Comment: Even for the first time it doesn't behave as expected? I have made a slight modification in my answer. You can check if it works

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear in my question :-(
The problem occurs when I leave the EditText. Then I expect the hint to move from label to EditText. It does not. It stays in the label.
This only occurs when I set an onFocusChangeListener on the EditText.

Comment: What I mean is to try  `if (!hasFocus) { setUsernameError("Indtast e-mail (eller brugernavn)"); editText.clearFocus()}`

Comment: You need to add `android:focusable` and `android:focusableInTouchMode` in your parentview

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is quite an old thread but I came up against this same issue today, resetting the hint animation fixed it for me;

```
    findViewById(R.id.username).setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            findViewById(R.id.usernameWrapper).setHintAnimationEnabled(hasFocus);
            if (!hasFocus) {
                setUsernameError("Indtast e-mail (eller brugernavn)");

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the internal EditText with `getEditText()` method and then call the `setOnFocusChangeListener`.
The code would look like this:

```
private TextInputLayout textInputEmail = findViewById(R.id.text_input_email);

textInputEmail.getEditText().setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lost the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

First you have to get the internal EditText with `getEditText()` method and then call the `setOnFocusChangeListener`.
The code would look like this:

```
private TextInputLayout textInputEmail = findViewById(R.id.text_input_email);

textInputEmail.getEditText().setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lost the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You seem to have duplicated your answer.